# Universality with respect to quotients

Tags: general-topology, quotient-spaces

Is there an infinite cardinal $\kappa$ for which the following statement (S) true?

(S) : There is a topology $\tau_\kappa$ on $\kappa$ such that for all topological spaces $(X,\tau)$ with $|X|\leq \kappa$ there is a binary relation $\sim$ on $\kappa$ such that $(X,\tau)\cong (\kappa,\tau_\kappa)/\sim$.

Comment: cool question +1 :)

Comment: Could you share some insights about this question? Like, how did it come up? Do you know a specific (finite or infinite) $\kappa$ for which (S) holds? Alternatively, do you have a reason to suspect the answer is yes? No?

Comment: Rustyn thanks :) AmitaiYuval: I was toying around with quotients of $\mathbb{R}$ wondering what spaces you can get if you just are "clever enough" with the equivalence relation. From these considerations I generalized and came up with the question above. - I suspect the answer is no for every cardinal $\kappa$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\kappa$ be an infinite cardinal. Let $X$ be a set of power $\kappa$, and let $\tau$ be a topology on $X$. There are $2^\kappa$ equivalence relations on $X$, so $\langle X,\tau\rangle$ has at most $2^\kappa$ distinct quotients.

For each $p\in\beta\kappa$ let $Y_p=\{p\}\cup\kappa$ with the topology that it inherits from $\beta\kappa$. For $p,q\in\beta\kappa$ the spaces $Y_p$ and $Y_q$ are homeomorphic iff the partial orders $\langle p,\subseteq\rangle$ and $\langle q,\subseteq\rangle$  are isomorphic, which is the case iff there is a bijection $\varphi:\kappa\to\kappa$ such that $q=\{\varphi[A]:A\in p\}$. There are $2^\kappa$ such bijections, but $|\beta\kappa|=2^{2^\kappa}$, so there are $2^{2^\kappa}$ pairwise non-homeomorphic spaces $Y_p$. Clearly almost all of them fail to be quotients of $\langle X,\tau\rangle$.